# Way to simulate hardware key press event

Tags: android, methods, input, instrumentation

I have custom `InputMethod` that have a `BroadcastListener` in it. When the listener catches an intent in `onReceive()` method I call the `onKey` method of my `InputMethod` and in that way I simulate a key press from the softkey board. If I call `onKeyDown` or `onKeyUp` then I simulate the hardware keyboard. So this is a solution that I dont like.

Yesterday I found this:
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/01/generating-keypresses-programmatically.html

Is it a good idea to use `Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync` to simulate key press and it is working perfectly, I don't even need to implement my own `InputMethod`. I mean this Instrumentation is provided for testing purpose as I understand.

Is it a good idea to be used in way I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too much to use your own `IME` to test your application.

You already have a way to do it with Android's `Instrumentation`.
You can also check [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) which might be useful for what you are trying to test.

Comment: Macarase thanks for the response but, the point is that I don't want to test anything, I just want to use the Instrumentation as normal logical part in the final release version of the application to generate user input data. Is this ok, will this work fine on any version of android, will there be any permission issues? And yes, there is no need of IME if I use Instrumentation, but is it ok to use it in the release version (not for testing).

Comment: You shouldn't use `Instrumentation` as part of your application. What are you trying to archive?

Comment: There is Intent that is sent from another application via broadcast (I dont have access to that application). In the intent there is an extra that is ASCII code of an character. So I want to catch it in my own application and send that character to the current InputMethod. I found two ways to do that. First is with my own IM that has an instance of the broadcast listener. The BL catches the Intent and then calls onKeyDown and onKeyUp methods of the IM. In the second one I use only BL that catches the intent and then calls Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync() which simulates the keypress.

Comment: Ofcourse the second way looks easier to me and the better part is that it will work with any IM that the user has installed. But now you said it's not a good idea to used it as part of my app, can you tell my why?

Comment: Because Instrumentation is just for testing and I guess you will not be able to upload an apk with instrumentation to the market.

Comment: You should have your application directly act on the character you receive in the Intent, rather than faking yourself out by pretending it is from the user.